# Using random.choice() with classes

Tags: python-3.x, class, random

As a predisposition to this post, I'm very new to programming. I've been a sound engineer for the last 5+ years but due to lack of work in my area I've decided to go back to school for software development. Classes start in September but while I have downtime due to the state of the world right now (Coronavirus), I figured I'd use my time to my advantage and get a head start. I've decided to start with python because the syntax is pretty simple and I have dabbled in it years ago when I was a kid.

Anyway, I was following along with youtube tutorials and just copying peoples code and felt like i wasn't learning anything. So once I had a basic concept of enough fundamentals to get started I figured I'd just started coding something and learn by trial and error, and documentation reading. I started to program a simple text based RPG game.

The problem I have encountered is when using the random.choice() function along with a list of objects representing monsters, when a monster is chosen with a certain set of stats and level etc, it locks them in as that initial choice. for example.

I have a list of two monster objects like so :

```
monster = [Monster_Blob("Blob", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Monster_Skeleton("Skeleton", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)]
pick = random.choice(monster)
```

Their stats inside the class such as Level are determined by random integers.
Then along with that the player has a search function:

```
def monster_search():
    global pick
    pick = random.choice(monster)
    print()
    print("You found a " + pick.Name)
    print()
    print("Name: " + str(pick.Name), "Level: " + str(pick.Lvl))
    print("HP: " + str(pick.BaseHP), "MP: " + str(pick.BaseMP))
    print("Str: " + str(pick.BaseStr), "Dex: " + str(pick.BaseDex))
    battle()
```

When the monsters HP is reduced to 0 and the battle function ends, when you call the search function again it repeats the same 2 monsters with the same stats that were locked in during the initial search. Is there something else I should be doing other than just defining pick as a random choice of monster during the search function?

I know this is pretty basic stuff but its had me stuck long enough that I took the time to write this out.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the type of monster to be determined by your random selection from a list, but for the monster's individual stats to be determined only after they're picked, not when you set up the original list.

In this case, I think you want to put the *classes* into the list, not instances of them. Then when you pick out a class, you can instantiate it and set up the random stats at that time.

```
class Skeleton:  # the monster types should be set up to do stat randomization in __init__
    ...

class Blob:
    ...

monster_types = [Skeleton, Blob]

def pick_monster():
    picked_type = random.choice(monster_types)
    monster = picked_type()   # this does Skeleton() or Blob()

    ... # do stuff with the monster here, or maybe return it
```

This is a neat example of a feature of Python's Object Oriented Programming model: Classes are themselves objects, so you can do stuff to them that you normally do to other kinds objects, like putting them into lists.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I do it this way and try to print the objects attribute, for example the name. being the monsterpickedvariable.Name, I get an error saying the object has no attribute 'Name'. Which it does.   And the funny thing is if I use if statements for each individual instance of monster in the list. Like the way i did it first, so monster = "[Monster_Blob(etc...),Monster_Skeleton(etc...)]. pick = random.choice(monster), then if pick == monster[0]: etc... The instances have varying stats every time the search function is called. So why would it work that way but not the other?